# ImmutableJS how to get a value inside an object?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have this Immutable Map and I need to get to the property `name`:
[image]

If I do `retrospective.get('users')` I can get inside the users, but if I do `retrospective.getIn(['users', 'name'])` It doesn't work... how can I access to the property `name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because `users` is an array. So you have to provide an index like this

```
retrospective.getIn(['users', 0, 'name'])
```

**Update:**

To get all names

```
retrospective.get('users').map(user => user.get('name'))
```

Comment: But how can I access to all the properties of `name` not only the first position?

Comment: I would try this with the `map` function.