# Immutable JS: Set property in object within array within object

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

Suppose I have an object like this:

```
const document = {
  items: [
    { notes: ['a', 'b'] },
    { notes: ['y', 'z'] },
  ]
}
```

I want to use Immutable JS to set a notes array on an item. Basically do an unshift, but immutable.

Here is what I am trying:

```
const immutableDocument = Immutable.fromJs(document);
immutableDocument.setIn(['items[index]', 'notes'], [newNote, ...oldNotes]);
```

It's not working, and I don't see anything in the documentation about accessing an array by a certain index (or predicate for that matter) within an Immutable object.

How would I accomplish this?

Update:
Based on [the answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546697/immutablejs-how-to-get-a-value-inside-an-object), I also tried `immutableDocument.setIn(['items', index, 'notes'], [newNote, ...oldNotes])`, and that does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

`const newDocument = Immutable.setIn(immutableDocument, ['items', index, 'notes'], [newNote, ...oldNotes]);`

Not entirely sure why the other one didn't work [based on the docs](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/setIn), but hey, I get to move on.